# Need to remove anaconda3 from $PATH

Tags: python, environment-variables

I imagine this is probably a duplicate, but I'm fairly new to Linux and all the other guides I've already checked seem to be referring to something different. I installed anaconda3 and accidentally told it to update the path variable. This is messing with all sorts of things for obvious reasons. When I `which python` I get `/home/sbendl/anaconda3/bin/python`,

and if I `echo $PATH` I get:

```
 /home/sbendl/anaconda3/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/sbendl/bin:/home/sbendl/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

but when I look at `/etc/environment` I don't see anything at all related to those. Clearly I'm confusing two different things. I would like to be able to continue using Python 3.5 when needed, but I want the default to be 2.7 so that I can use anything else that assumes 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To completely remove `anaconda` from your path:

- Check for the `anaconda` entry in both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` and remove the line:

  ```
  export PATH="/home/sbendl/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
  ```

For complete removal:

- Remove the entries in the files stated above then get rid of the `~/anaconda2` dir.

And that should correct the issue.

Comment: I found it as a section on the bottom of bashrc. I typed: sudo nano  ~/.bashrc in the terminal to remove the section

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is added to the `PATH` for all users in the `/etc/profile` file. This can be verified with:

```
$ cat /etc/profile | grep anaconda
export PATH=/opt/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

To remove it simply comment out the line by preceding it with the `#` character. Editing this file likely needs `sudo`:

```
$ sudo pico /etc/profile
```

If a particular user requires Anaconda, the `export` command can be added to the user's `.bashrc` or `.profile` file.

Answer (score 0):

Its 2021 now and I am running anaconda3, which is great until you don't want to author in the anaconda3 environment anymore. Even after commenting the entire anaconda3 initialization function in the ~/.bashrc, I was still having my PATH set to ~/anaconda3/bin/

I had to actually rename the anaconda3 directory to break it from setting the PATH var which apparently is now buried somewhere in ~/anaconda3/

After I did this my python path returned to /usr/bin/python where I am properly using update-alternatives to manage my various python installations.  Anaconda SHOULD move to using this method on Debian/Ubuntu so that we don't have to wreck the install just to set the proper PATH.