# Uninstalling Anaconda in Ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to remove Anaconda2 from my Ubuntu server as it is clashing with other versions of Python. As mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878068/need-to-remove-anaconda3-from-path/878077), I cleared the lines `~./bashrc` containing reference to anaconda2. When I try to do the same for the file `~./bash_profile`, for some reason the file is already empty.

Nevertheless, when I type `python -V`, it displays

```
-bash: /home/kasa/anaconda2/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what else needs to done to erase this anaconda installation.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer. I had to run the following lines `$ rm -rf ~/anaconda2
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda_backup
$ rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
`

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You are encouraged to post your solution as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)!

Comment: That *specific* error message likely indicated that your shell had hashed the previous location for `python` - you probably could have solved it using `hash -d python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed there were residual files on my server. I had run the following commands to completely remove any references to anaconda2.

```
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda2 
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda_backup 
$ rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```